# No temp file in MAMP whilst trying to upload - no file found

Tags: php, mamp

I have never had this problem before. I am testing an image upload script on my local server (MAMP on Macbook) and I am getting errors that the temporary file cannot be found when trying to obtain information from the file.

This is one of the errors I get:

getimagesize(/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpqQboYy): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

The directory is definitely there and has the correct permissions but for some reason the temp file just isn't being saved to it (I have looked inside the directory and used file_exists.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem (as I say I have not had it before)?

@deceze I am not sure this is the same problem as I initially assign the $_FILES array to a new variable and then I am passing that variable as a parameter into a class function where I am trying to resize and save the image and it is within the class function that the error is occurring. But maybe I am wrong.

```
$imageFiles = $_FILES['imageFiles'];

$objImage->uploadImage($imageFiles, 180);
```

In the class:

```
public function uploadImage($file, $maxWidth = '', $maxHeight = '', $addWatermark = true)
{
    if (!file_exists($file['tmp_name'])) {
        echo 'No temp file'; // For Temp checking only
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you possibly storing `$_FILES[..]['tmp_name']` in `$_SESSION` and are doing `getimagesize` on the *next* page or something...?!

Comment: Closing question as duplicate purely on the above suspicion. Leave a comment if that is not so and provide code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @deceze I am not sure this is the same problem as I initially assign the $_FILES array to a new variable and then I am passing that variable as a parameter into a class function where I am trying to resize and save the image and it is within the class function that the error is occurring. But maybe I am wrong.

`$imageFiles = $_FILES['imageFiles'];`

`$objImage->uploadImage($imageFiles, 180)`

In the class:

`public function uploadImage($file, $maxWidth = '', $maxHeight = '', $addWatermark = true) { if (!file_exists($file['tmp_name'])) { echo 'No temp file'; // Temp checking } }`

Comment: OK, I have now tested in the same file that instantiates and makes calls to the class and it works, so it appears it is a problem with sending through to another file as per the answered question.